# MNISTデータセットを使いたい

Tags: github, 深層学習

オライリーの「ゼロから始めるディープラーニング」という本で、ディープラーニングを勉強しています。P.73でMNISTデータセット（手書き数字の画像セット）をGitHubから入手するのですが、やり方がわからず、止まっています。リンク先は https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch です。環境はwindowsでjupyter notebookを使っています。

本には以下のように書いてあります。

> 本書では、MNISTデータセットのダウンロードから画像データのNumpy配列への変換までをサポートする便利なPythonスクリプトであるmnist.pyを提供しています（mnist.pyは、datasetディレクトリに存在します）。このmnist.pyの利用に際しては、カレントディレクトリがch01,ch02,ch03,....,ch08ディレクトリのいずれかである必要があります。このmnist.pyの関数load_mnist()を用いれば、MNISTデータを次のように簡単に読み込むことができます。

Comment: 「mnist.pyの関数load_mnist()を用いれば」と引用したところに書いてあるし、githubの中のソースにその関数を使っているソースもあるのですが、わからないことはなんでしょうか? あと、"jupyter notebookを使っています"の意味もわかりません。本に書いてあるコードはそのまま使いたくないし読みたくもないが関数だけは使いたいということですか?

Comment: ch01,ch02,ch03,....,ch08の各ディレクトリ配下にあるからスクリプトから、`mnist.py`の関数`load_mnist()`が呼ばれるようなつくりになっています。これらのディレクトリに移動(cd)して、スクリプトを実行すれば自動的にMNISTのデータがダウンロードされます。ダウンロードできないとすれば、ディレクトリに移動していないか、ネットワークの設定などに問題があり（例えば、必要なプロキシーサーバーを経由していないとか）、ダウンロードできないかのどちらかではかいかと思います。エラーが出ているのであれば、そのエラーメッセージを質問に追記してください。

Comment: 本を見てみたらその箇所のすぐ下にまさに実際に使っているコードが書いてありますね。これの動かし方がわからない、という質問ですか?

Comment: 実際に詰まっているチャプターがどこか教えていただけますか？単純なコードミスなども考えられますので。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**回答**
datasetと同じ並びにフォルダを作成し、そのフォルダで実行するか、datasetの完全パスを`sys.path.append`で追加すればMNISTデータセットを取得できます。

---

> MNISTデータセット（手書き数字の画像セット）をGitHubから入手するのですが、やり方がわからず、止まっています。リンク先は https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch です。環境はwindowsでjupyter notebookを使っています。

例えば`ch03`の`mnist_show.py`では以下のコードで`http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/`からMNISTデータセットを取得してくれます。

```
from dataset.mnist import load_mnist
(x_train, t_train), (x_test, t_test) = load_mnist(flatten=True, normalize=False)
```

同じく`ch03`の`mnist_show.py`に以下のコードがあります。

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.pardir)  # 親ディレクトリのファイルをインポートするための設定
```

これは`dataset`が`ch03`と同じ並びにありますので、親ディレクトリをパスに追加しています。
注意書きにありますよう、`dataset`と同じ並びのディレクトリ下で実行すればMNISTデータセットを取得してくれるはずです。

> このmnist.pyの利用に際しては、カレントディレクトリがch01,ch02,ch03,....,ch08ディレクトリのいずれかである必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

書籍でどのような解説になっているかわかりませんが、GitHubから単にデータをダウンロードするだけであれば、リンク先(リポジトリ)をブラウザで開いて緑色の「**Clone or Download**」をクリック、ポップアップ表示されたメニューで「**Download ZIP**」をクリックすればデータをZIP形式でダウンロードできます。

ダウンロードしたファイルを適当なフォルダ(実行環境)で展開すれば`ch01, ch02, ...`の各フォルダ等が出てくるはずです。

Answer (score 0):

[image: ZIPダウンロード]

githubのファイルダウンロードであれば、上の画像にある「DOWNLOAD ZIP」から行えますよ。
（ちなみにこちらの画像は、別のgithubページのものです）
他にも、Scikit-learn経由で簡単にインポートする方法なども下のサイトで紹介されています。ご参考までに
https://www.codexa.net/cnn-mnist-keras-beginner/